# How many spurs from lighting terminal?

Tags: lighting

I am looking to add a new light and the best access I have is from an adjacent room's light fitting. This ceiling rose has 3 supply lines, which I assume is a supply in, supply out and a spur.

Is it OK to add another spur from this fitting?

I am also unsure where this spur goes as the other light fittings also have 2-3 supply cables. How would I find out which of these 3 supply lines are the in & out? Is it a matter of disconnecting 1 and seeing which lights are not switching on?

Comment: Based on terminology, I suspect you are in UK, or at least not in USA/Canada. That may be relevant to determining proper wiring. So where are you?

Comment: I am in the UK.

Comment: I don't believe there's a "number of spurs" rule, but you'll hit a practical limit based on other rules, such as box fill, which will limit the number of wires or cables you can terminate in the box.